# How good is Enfinity as an e-commerce solution?

Tags: java, frameworks, e-commerce, enfinity, intershop

I've started learning enfinity suite and wonder if it's a good e-commerce solution. So far I've noticed that it's extremely heavyweight (as to me, who never worked with any ecommerce soft) and lacks qualified support.

P.S.: Answers of those who tried Enfinity before are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not, and here is why:

- no community at all (if to disregard paid support ^^)
- heavyweight
- slow (though, CPU usage is outrageous)
- contains a lot of redundant architectural approaches (this covers all layers)
- includes numerous self-implemented tiers (i.e. ORM) in stead of which open source ones could have been used more efficiently
- complex: learning curve is enormous

From a developer perspective:

- java code is being written quite rarely (even for core development, though it depends)
- doesn't have much to learn (no technologies, no complex architectural approaches except for those, caused by previous redundant development)

Answer (score 2):

If it's extremely heavyweight and lacks support then it's not a great e-commerce solution.

Another thing to consider is the size and quality of the community using the product.

For example:

- Can you Google for answers to common problems?
- Can you find active support groups?
- Is there an appreciable number of companies relying on this product?
- etc.

Comment: As for companies, well, there's this http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/ .

Comment: You might need to put a bounty on this one to get a serious bite. I want to say that the lack of interest from the SO community means a lack of interest in general but... Your only tag initially was "ecommerce" which one I'm sure people tend not to include when filtering by tags. Which means you missed your initial opportunity for serious consideration. (Questions not addressed within a few minutes on SO tend to go stagnant very quickly.)

Comment: There was no enfinity tag before) I think this should be unanswered until someone experienced will post his/her thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well i was working on Enfinity from the last 3+ years and here are my inputs for the Enfinity
1) Good Platfrom for development with very quick start time and solid platform

now lets come to other side
1) Quite heavy needs lots of Disk space around 5+ GB and Good amount of RAM
2) Its not very much moduler and you have to install every module no matter you are using it or not..
3) Have to use Oracle as there ORM framework has been build for Oracle itself 
4) When it come for customization if one has no prior exp than it means digging and digging and digging

one more when it comes to hosting you have to find some one with intershop hosting.

Comment: I don't agree. 1) Very quick is something I wouldn't dare say about Enfinity. If no prior experience the start time for a developer varies from 1 to 3 weeks just to get the basics. And execution is slowed by the modularity system (1-3 secs of waiting is a lot!). 2) "you have to install every module no matter you are using it or not" it depends on what you define as a module, please clarify. 3) ORM framework is literally a pain in the arse, they'd better turn to Hibernate. 4)If it wasn't for customization I cant tell why someone would use it at all.

Comment: Well quick productive means once you get a basic idea you are about to go and i am agree 1-3 weeks are minimum learning curve.By Module i mean that they have certain module for certain specific functionality like bc_pricing this module have some very core and advance functionality about price calucaltions but not all e-commerce application needs them there are more such module(cartridges) which in some application are of no use but when you installing intershop you have to get them as part of it no matter if you are using or not.Regarding ORM yes i am agree with you as it is not that flexible

Comment: yes by customization if you have to customize there any process it require you to have some clear understanding of there platform and which i must say is not easy task at all

Comment: I haven't actually tried it with default cartridges, but if you don't need a cartridge, you can easily prevent it from being loaded by setting up certain params in config files and, to be 100% sure, simply delete it from the cartridges directory. If server crashes on startup, then apparently it is used somewhere. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: well yes we can do this by cartridgeslist.properties file but that is only with respect to what you want the server to load on startup.i was talking like what hybris currently doing they for e.g have some core module which one need in order to start basic application and when you need something for printing download and use that module.on other hands what i did not liked about the intershop is that there design is not moduler, but as per my information with there coming release of 6.5 they are working on this design

Comment: Please, clarify, which exactly design is not modular. Because if that was concerning cartridge structure principle in 6.5, most certainly you are mistaking.